# how can I correct my reconciliation of .csv files to remove dupes/nulls

Tags: powershell, csv, reconciliation

I have been using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74048270/45375) to check for additions/changes to class rosters from MS Teams:

```
$set = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]] (Import-CSV -Path stundent.csv).UserPrincipalName,
    [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
)
Import-Csv ad.csv | Where-Object { $set.Add($_.UserPrincipalName) } |
    Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Ideally, I want to be able to check if there have been removals when compared to a new file, swap the import file positions, and check for additions. If my files look like Source1 and Source2 (below), the check for removals would return Export1, and the check for additions would return Export2.
Since there will be multiple instances of students across multiple classes, I want to include TeamDesc in the filter query to make sure only the specific instance of that student with that class is returned.

Source1.csv

| TeamDesc | UserPrincipalName | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team 1 | student1@domain.com | john smith |
| Team 1 | student2@domain.com | nancy drew |
| Team 2 | student3@domain.com | harvey dent |
| Team 3 | student1@domain.com | john smith |

Source2.csv

| TeamDesc | UserPrincipalName | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team 1 | student2@domain.com | nancy drew |
| Team 2 | student3@domain.com | harvey dent |
| Team 2 | student4@domain.com | tim tams |
| Team 3 | student1@domain.com | john smith |

Export1.csv

| TeamDesc | UserPrincipalName | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team 1 | student1@domain.com | john smith |

Export2.csv

| TeamDesc | UserPrincipalName | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team 2 | student4@domain.com | tim tams |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, which uses [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) to compare the CSV files by *two* column values, simply by passing the property (column) names of interest to `-Property`; the resulting output is split into two collections based on which input side a differing property combination is unique to, using the [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where):

```
$removed, $added = (
  Compare-Object (Import-Csv Source1.csv) (Import-Csv Source2.csv) -PassThru `
                 -Property TeamDesc, UserPrincipalName
).Where({ $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }, 'Split')

$removed | 
  Select-Object -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation Export1.csv

$added |
  Select-Object -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation Export2.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both Csvs are stored in memory, `Source1.csv` is `$csv1` and `Source2.csv` is `$csv2`, you already have the logic for `Export2.csv` using the [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0):

```bash
$set = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]] $csv1.UserPrincipalName,
    [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
)
$csv2 | Where-Object { $set.Add($_.UserPrincipalName) }
```

Outputs:

```
TeamDesc UserPrincipalName   Name
-------- -----------------   ----
Team 2   student4@domain.com tim tams
```

For the first requirement, `Export1.csv`, the reference object would be `$csv2` and instead of a `HashSet<T>` you could use a [hash table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#creating-ordered-dictionaries), [`Group-Object -AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-7-group-objects-in-a-hash-table) makes it really easy in this case:

```bash
$map = $csv2 | Group-Object UserPrincipalName -AsHashTable -AsString

# if Csv2 has unique values for `UserPrincipalName`
$csv1 | Where-Object { $map[$_.UserPrincipalName].TeamDesc -ne $_.TeamDesc }

# if Csv2 has duplicated values for `UserPrincipalName`
$csv1 | Where-Object { $_.TeamDesc -notin $map[$_.UserPrincipalName].TeamDesc }
```

Outputs:

```
TeamDesc UserPrincipalName   Name
-------- -----------------   ----
Team 1   student1@domain.com john smith
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [How to compare two CSV files and output the rows that are just in either of the file but not in both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72012355/1701026) and [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)):

**Loading your sample data:**
<sup>(In your case you probably want to use `Import-Csv` to import your data)</sup>

```
Install-Script -Name Read-HtmlTable
$Csv1 = Read-HtmlTable https://stackoverflow.com/q/74452725 -Table 0 # Import-Csv .\Source1.csv
$Csv2 = Read-HtmlTable https://stackoverflow.com/q/74452725 -Table 1 # Import-Csv .\Source2.csv
```

```
Install-Module -Name JoinModule
$Csv1 |OuterJoin $Csv2 -On TeamDesc, UserPrincipalName -Name Out,In

TeamDesc UserPrincipalName   OutName    InName
-------- -----------------   -------    ------
Team 1   student1@domain.com john smith
Team 2   student4@domain.com            tim tams
```

You might use the (single) result file as is. If you really want to work with two different files, you might split the results as in the nice answer from **[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)**.